# how i can access data from helpers controller in angular meteor

Tags: angular-meteor

```
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$reactive','$filter', function ($scope, $state, $reactive, $filter) {
        console.log('username:' + $scope.name);
        this.relevantId = "etp59iEcDbvuMq8vf";
        this.subscribe('role');
        this.helpers({
                roleData: () => {
                return role.findOne({ _id: this.getReactively('relevantId') });
              }
         });
        console.log('ownerID: is roledata' + JSON.stringify(this.roledata;));
 }]);
```

Comment: Please note that once you post code on Stack Overflow, it is no longer yours.

Comment: @ArK Please ensure you fix all problems with a post when editing.

Comment: @ArK I know it is, but editors need to fix any issues that exist with the post when they're editing (as well as improving it if possible). Nice to see someone who's actually read the edit wiki (most users haven't and as a result many edits are rejected that improve the post, when the reviewers think it's not allowed) :-).